# PHP oci_execute for Multiple Statements

Tags: php, sql, oracle, sql-insert, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to issue multiple INSERT statements within a single `oci_execute()` call on PHP. The problem is that I get this error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I'm guessing it's the `;` after each statement.

So now, my question is how do I make multiple INSERT statements that would work within `oci_execute()`?

Here's my query so far:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(1, 'John');
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Martha');
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(3, 'Richard')
```

**EDIT**:

Note that there is no `;` at the end of my query because I'm using SQL statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wrap all statement into anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(1, 'John');
    INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Martha');
    INSERT INTO tbl (id, name) VALUES(3, 'Richard');    
END;
```

Oracle doesn't support batch of commands. Anonymous PL/SQL block is executed as single command.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Mind explaining why I need to do it this way?