# How to drop and create Oracle Database tables in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have code which create all my database with 13 tables.

I would like to add possibility to drop those tables (already got this) and add them new and empty.

My code:

```
include 'connection.php';

$c = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$createDb = "CREATE TABLE adres (
    adresid        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    miasto         VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    ulica          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    kod_pocztowy   CHAR(11 CHAR),
    nr_mieszkania  CHAR(5 CHAR),
    nr_domu        CHAR(5 CHAR)
);";

$ex = oci_parse($c,$createDb);
oci_execute($ex);
```

In response i got warning:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: try removing the semi colon in your create statement

Comment: This worked for one table. But can i have all queries in one $createDb variable?

Comment: @BartolV9 : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945939/php-oci-execute-for-multiple-statements

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz not working for create table

Comment: As a hint, here's a common technique: `begin execute immediate 'drop table TestTempTable'; exception when others then if sqlcode <> -942 then raise; end if; end;`

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your create statements into a table temp1 which you can create and insert using oci_parse and oci_execute 
and then you can use the PLSQL block to run your code using oci_parse and oci_execute.
Also, remove semicolon wherever required.

Step1

```
        CREATE TABLE temp1
      (
         id       NUMBER,
         sql_text CLOB
      );
```

Step2

```
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp1
    VALUES     (1,
                'drop table t2 ;drop table t3;');
    INSERT INTO temp1
    VALUES     (2,
                'create table t2 (t number);create table t3 (t1 number);');
    END;
```

Step3

```
            BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (SELECT blk.id,
                           TRIM(Regexp_substr(sql_text, '[^;]+', 1, lvl)) sql_text
                    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT id,
                                            LEVEL lvl
                            FROM   temp1
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(Trim(sql_text), '[^;]+'
                                                ))
                           blk,
                           temp1
                    WHERE  blk.id = temp1.id
                    ORDER  BY blk.id,
                              lvl) LOOP
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.sql_text;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  dbms_output.Put_line(SQLERRM);
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

or you can combine all three into one PLSQL block and call in oci_parse and oci_execute

```
                BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE temp1';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE temp1
              (
                 id       NUMBER,
                 sql_text CLOB
              )';

        INSERT INTO temp1
        VALUES      (1,
                     'drop table t2 ;drop table t3;');

        INSERT INTO temp1
        VALUES      (2,
                     'create table t2 (t number);create table t3 (t1 number);');


        FOR rec IN (SELECT blk.id,
                           TRIM(Regexp_substr(sql_text, '[^;]+', 1, lvl)) sql_text
                    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT id,
                                            LEVEL lvl
                            FROM   temp1
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(Trim(sql_text), '[^;]+'
                                                ))
                           blk,
                           temp1
                    WHERE  blk.id = temp1.id
                    ORDER  BY blk.id,
                              lvl) LOOP
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.sql_text;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  dbms_output.Put_line(SQLERRM);
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```